# Was the Holiday episode of Warehouse 13 canon?

Tags: warehouse-13

In season 2, episode 12 of Warehouse 13, it shows Myka leaving the Warehouse because she feels like she's a liability.

The very next episode, it shows Myka in the Warehouse as if she had never left, and they have a Santa Clause related assignment.

Is this episode part of the over all story? Or is it just a bonus holiday episode?

Comment: I call this the DBZ movie effect. By this I mean that some productions like to create side story arcs in the form of movies or singular episodes that are impossible to place in the flow of the main story arc. For most of the Dragon Ball Z movies it's almost impossible to place it in comparison to the series (the main exception being the Bardock movie)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Yay! Found a better reference:

> Courtesy of Ian Stokes (one of the writers for the show) via Twitter:
>
> "For hardcore fans who need continuity, last night's #Warehouse13 **takes place before "Vendetta"** but after the one where Picard became a Borg"

---

According to [this review](http://www.tvfanatic.com/2010/12/warehouse-13-review-secret-santa/) of "Secret Santa" episode,

> I’ll say up front that SyFy very specifically-stated (in multiple places) that "Secret Santa" would not address anything related to Myka leaving on the September finale.

Also, from http://www.tv.com/shows/warehouse-13/secret-santa-1365486/ - not sure whether the info is canonical or someone pulled out of thin air:

> This episode is set out of continuity, as it takes place prior to the events of the preceding episode, the season finale, when Myka resigned as an agent.

This analysis also seems to confirm the fact: http://airlockalpha.com/node/8138/warehouse-13-secret-santa.html

> As soon as "Secret Santa" begins with a storybook "Once upon a time in South Dakota," it's probably for the best to assume that this episode either takes place outside of the actual series continuity thus far or maybe happened in between other episodes (but presumably after "Vendetta"). This continues as Pete voiceovers "A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away" and Myka argues with him that "this is a Christmas show."

Comment: I don't watch the show, so maybe it's an inside joke, but I don't quite get the "after the one where Picard became a Borg" line.

Comment: Watch Star Trek: TNG then.

Comment: @Keen: I grew up on TNG. What I'm unclear on is its connection to Warehouse 13 in this case, unless Ian Stokes was just using it as a time reference that was meant to be comically long before (i.e. "When were you born?" "Sometime between the beginning of time and now.").

Comment: I'm sure that's where he was going with it.

Comment: @gnovice I believe he was referencing H.G turning evil, but didn't want to spoil it for those who haven't seen that episode yet. This makes sense in terms of continuity, since H.G isn't present in the Christmas episode.